# OBOUT Suite: HTML Editor imposible to Upload Images

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-editor, obout

I am using the HTML Editor from OBOUT, but i cant ENABLE the option to upload images in the editor, it appears in gray.

How can i enable the upload images in the Obout Editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create folders and upload images in MANAGED folders only.
You can manage it yourself -  set the 'ManagedFolders' property of 'ImageBrowser' popup.
See http://www.obout.com/Obout.Ajax.UI/HTMLEditor/docs/server/Popups/ImageBrowser.aspx ,
http://www.obout.com/Obout.Ajax.UI/HTMLEditor/KnowledgeBase.aspx?id=895 /